# Access @Environment object from UIViewControllerRepresentable object

Tags: swiftui, environmentobject, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I used this approach to incorporate camera with swiftUI:
https://medium.com/@gaspard.rosay/create-a-camera-app-with-swiftui-60876fcb9118

The UIViewControllerRepresentable is implemented by PageFourView class. PageFourView is one of the TabView of the parental View. I have an `@EnvironmentObject` passed from the SceneDelegate to the parent view and then to PageFourView. But when I am trying to acess `@EnvironmentObject` from   makeUIViewController method of PageFourView I get an error:

> Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Data found. A
> View.environmentObject(_:) for Data may be missing as an ancestor of
> this view

... even though I can see the @Environment object from context.environment. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine


final class PageFourView: UIViewController, UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    public typealias UIViewControllerType = PageFourView
    
    @EnvironmentObject var data: Data
    
    var previewView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        previewView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
        
        previewView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(previewView)
        
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PageFourView>) -> PageFourView {
        print(context.environment)
        print(self.data.Name)
        return PageFourView()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PageFourView, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PageFourView>) {
    }
}

struct PageFourView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var data = Data()
    static var previews: some View {
        PageFourView().environmentObject(self.data)
    }
}
```

here is the parental view that PageFourView is called from:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AppView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var data: Data
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            PageOneView().environmentObject(data)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("PageOne")
                }

            PageTwoView().environmentObject(data)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("PageTwo")
                }
            PageThreeView().environmentObject(data)
            .tabItem {
                Text("PageThree")
            }
            PageFourView().environmentObject(data)
            .tabItem {
                Text("PageFour")
            }
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct AppView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @State static var data = Data()
    static var previews: some View {
        AppView().environmentObject(self.data)
    }
}
```

```
final class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
    let cameraController = CameraController()
    var previewView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        previewView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
        previewView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(previewView)

        cameraController.prepare {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }

            try? self.cameraController.displayPreview(on: self.previewView)
        }

    }
}


extension CameraViewController : UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    public typealias UIViewControllerType = CameraViewController

    public func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraViewController>) -> CameraViewController {
        return CameraViewController()
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraViewController>) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the view, where you are using PageFourView?

Comment: Just edited my post by adding the parental view.

Comment: I reproduced the issue.. actually @EnvironmentObject should be available in ViewRepresentable and should work. However, still crashing for me either

Answer (score 3):

And `UIViewRepresentable` and `UIViewControllerRepresentable` is-a `View` and **must be a struct**.

In described case controller representable is not needed, because you operate with view, so here is corrected code:

```
struct PageFourView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: Data

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, 
                          height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
        view.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit

        print(context.environment)
        print(self.data.Name)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

btw, you don't need to pass `.environmentObject` to subviews in same view hierarchy, only for new hierarchy, like sheets, so you can use simplified code as below

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        PageOneView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("PageOne")
            }
        PageTwoView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("PageTwo")
            }
        PageThreeView()
        .tabItem {
            Text("PageThree")
        }
        PageFourView()
        .tabItem {
            Text("PageFour")
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** for `CameraViewController` just wrap it as below

```
struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CameraViewController {
        CameraViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job.. I tried that several times yesterday I just didn’t noticed it is declared as class..

Comment: Asperi, thank you for your solution. But the problem is that I am trying to implement camera in swiftUI, and approach I found is this one: https://medium.com/@gaspard.rosay/create-a-camera-app-with-swiftui-60876fcb9118 (I posted link in my original post). And here is the implementation https://github.com/RosayGaspard/SwiftUI-Simple-camera-app/commit/0c2752f8f6f8f8e28973960d1ae7a2eea80c1616 I hope that their CameraViewController could be rewritten at struct.

Comment: Asperi, I mean camera implementation that I am trying to use seems to require that UIViewControllerRepresentative  is a class, because of the methods it needs to access camera. the implementation is given here: https://github.com/RosayGaspard/SwiftUI-Simple-camera-app/commit/0c2752f8f6f8f8e28973960d1ae7a2eea80c1616   I updated my original post with their implementation of UIViewControllerRepresentative from the above link.